# Error when adding music files to the AudioTrack list - WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, audio-player, background-audio, known-folders

I'm new to on the app development scene, and I'm building a music player for Windows Phone.
The problem is when I try to import music from the local Music Library to my app.

I have an AudioPlaybackAgent and a List of music that it will play.
Here's the list:

```
public static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
        {
            new AudioTrack(new Uri("Chama os Mulekes.mp3", UriKind.Relative), 
                    "Chama os Mulekes", 
                    "ConeCrewDiretoria", 
                    "Com os Neurônios Evoluindo", 
                    new Uri("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-_d2oha1QzNM/UhjYxv3XsLI/AAAAAAAAAWk/QyWgG7ilTAs/s0-d/Cone-Crew-Diretoria-Com-os-neuronios-evoluindo.jpg", UriKind.Absolute))
        };
```

I added a button to the interface that when clicked it imports the local music library files to that playlist. Here's the code:

```
private async void ImportButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var musicLibrary = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (StorageFile _file in musicLibrary)
            {
                var musicTags = await _file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
                MusicPlusAgent.AudioPlayer._playList.Add
                    (new AudioTrack (new Uri(_file.Path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                        musicTags.Title,
                        musicTags.Artist,
                        musicTags.Album,
                        null));
            }
        }
```

When run the app and touch the play button, the preset music plays fine, but when I touch the import button the app crashes.
Any idea on what's wrong here?

Ps. Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone `BackgroundAudioPlayer` API pre-dates the WinRT `StorageFolder` API and thus it doesn't work with those types of files (but is still available for back-compat). `BackgroundAudioPlayer` (and thus `AudioTrack`) is designed to play HTTP URLs and files from your local isolated storage folder. See [this MSDN walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx) for more information.

Note that you can't use the XNA-based `MediaLibrary` APIs either to implement your own background-audio player. It is assumed that the user will use the built-in music player to play those files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I rewrote this app for WP8.1, as it can be a lot more functional.